# Django Rest Framework Routing for embedded Angular Applications

Tags: django, angular, routes, django-rest-framework, static-files

I'm trying to bundle an Angular app and deploy it as static content in a Django Rest Framework DRF application.

I don't know Django or DRF at all however, I want to take control of the routing to express something like this:

For /admin/* - delegate to built-in Django admin.

For /api/* - delegate to Django Rest Framework

For / only, and /* - treat as static content loaded from "some specified project folder", so
 / maps to file ./static/index.html
 /assets/pic.jpg maps to ./static/assets/pic.jpg

I've not been able to achieve the above. All I have is this:

A template view for index.html living at ./templates/index.html - This is the from the Angular project and is not a Django template.

Other webpack bundled content copied manually to ./static such as vendor.|hash|.bundle.js

Another problem is what to do with Assets. In the angular project, HTML views refer to assets via /assets which is at the same level as index.html

I've gotten some control over paths using this command line:

```
ng build --deploy-url=/static --output-path=../backend/tutorial/static
```

The deploy-url arg results in bundled assets references in index.html being prefixed by /static which means that Django can serve them (but not favicon.ico for some reason).

The output-path arg dumps all the assets somewhere other than the default "dist" folder.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

Url patterns looks like the above.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

These are the static settings. What I need is to be able to say "/static" and "/assets" are both static asset folders.

I'm not sure what TemplateView is (urlPatterns). Maybe there's a StaticFilesView or something that maps a URL to a path on disk?

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote 
>   These are the static settings. What I need is to be able to say "/static" and "/assets" are both static asset folders.
>   Blockquote

You can achieve that with the following steps:

1. Add /assets static directory in NGINX site configuration file:

   ```
   server {
       ....
       ....
       # your Django project's static files - required
       location /static {
           alias /path/to.../static;
       }
       # your Angular project's static files
       location /assets {
           alias /path/to.../assets;
       }
       ....
       ....
   }
   ```
2. In your Django urls.py add:

   ```
   from django.views.static import serve as static_serve

   urlpatterns = [
       ....
       url(r'^assets/(?P<path>.*)$', static_serve,     
                     {'document_root':'/path/to.../assets'}), 
       ....
       ....
   ]
   ```

**That's it**. You don't have to touch the static configuration in Django settings.

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media')
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reservation_exchange', 'static'),
    )
```